# Contar repetições em SQL com INTERSECT e COUNT

Tags: sql

Tenho uma tabela SQL com centenas de dados, e gostaria de ao introduzir um array, o mesmo fosse comparado com essa tabela e informa-se quantas repetições ocorreram. (Tabela --> EVENTO | DADOS1 | DADOS2 | DADOS3 | DADOS4 | DADOS5 | DADOS6 | DADOS7 |DADOS8)

Conseguir comparar 2 eventos dessa tabela entre si, mas quero comparar 1 com toda a tabela e ver a quantidade de repetições. Por exemplo ao comparar o evento 1247 ele informará que com 1 coincidência (dados1 iguais em ambos, mas todos os outros diferentes) teve 750 ocorrências, 2 coincidências (dados1 e dados4 iguais em ambos e os outros diferentes - independente qual dado foi igual a qual, o que importa e que teve 2 coincidências) tiveram 500 ocorrências, 3 coincidências 470 ocorrências, 4 coincidências 350 ocorrências, até 8 coincidências 2 ocorrências.

Em SQL comparar 2 valores seria:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
SELECT T.[DADOS1], T.[DADOS2], T.[DADOS3], T.[DADOS4], T.[DADOS5], T.[DADOS6], T.[DADOS7], T.[DADOS8] FROM [TABELA1] AS T WHERE [EVENTO] = 1
INTERSECT
SELECT T.[DADOS1], T.[DADOS2], T.[DADOS3], T.[DADOS4], T.[DADOS5], T.[DADOS6], T.[DADOS7], T.[DADOS8] FROM [TABELA1] AS T WHERE [EVENTO] = 3
) I
```

Comment: Se quer : concidência exata em todos os campos um a um campo1 x campo1 campo2 x campo2 etc OU  campo1 ratela contra qualquer campo da tabela2 ?

Comment: Campo 1 ratela contra qualquer campo da tabela 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
--crie duas views do tipo
create view v_tabela 1 as
select '1' ordem,campo1 campo from tabela1 union all
select '2' ordem,campo2 campo from tabela2 union all
...
/*idem tabela2*/

--localizando
select campo from v_tabela1 
intersect
select campo from v_tabela2

--listando

select * from v_tabela1
where campo in (select campo
                from (select campo from v_tabela1 
                      intersect
                      select campo from v_tabela2))
```